# React efficiently update (render) new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that fetches some data like this

```
const data = fetch(API)
setState([...state, data])
```

I append new data to the state in a list form.
This is how I render my data,

```
return (state.map(d => <Component data={d}/>))
```

This is getting really slow when I append more and more data. Is there a way that instead of re-render the existing components, you just append a new component with new data to the existing list of components?

Comment: How many components are you rendering? Also what does your data look like and what kind of components are they?

Comment: There is a button for user to click and fetch data. There can be many as it can be, but they usually get slow when there are more than 3 sets of data. <Component/> renders a scatter plot and a line chart and the y-axis labels have some click interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer really depends on size of dataset:

- If less than 10000 probably React.memo + react-fast-compare done well for you

```js
import React from 'react';
import isEqual from 'react-fast-compare';
const YourComponent = props => {...}
export default React.memo(YourComponent, isEqual);
```

- If more than 10000 you should look into specialized libraries such as [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your applications is getting slow, because your component re-renders even if the data stays the same. You could use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)/[React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) in your `<Component />` to avoid this.

Also you should use a unique [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in your `state.map`, which is also important to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: It doesn't help on really big datasets (for example more than 10000 elements)